# asynchronicity between flask-sqlalchemy connections

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying out flask-sqlalchemy for a new project, with no experience on flask and neither on sqlalchemy.

I wanted to understand the behavior of the `db.session` transactions when using different database connections simultaneously (via the `SQLALCHEMY_BINDS` configuration).
I defined three different models, using two different db connections (both sqlite), dispatched using the model class attribute `__bind_key__`.

The application code is something like:

```
    db.session.add(First(foo='foo', second=Second(bar='bar')))  # models on the first bind key
    db.session.add(Third(baz='baz'))  # model on the second bind key
    db.session.commit()
```

The query log (logged via "SQLALCHEMY_ECHO" configuration on standard error) is something like

```
2016-09-16 14:31:12,602 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2016-09-16 14:31:12,603 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine INSERT INTO second (bar) VALUES (?)
2016-09-16 14:31:12,603 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ('bar',)
2016-09-16 14:31:12,604 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2016-09-16 14:31:12,604 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine INSERT INTO third (baz) VALUES (?)
2016-09-16 14:31:12,604 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ('baz',)
2016-09-16 14:31:12,606 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine INSERT INTO first (foo, second_id) VALUES (?, ?)
2016-09-16 14:31:12,606 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ('foo', 1)
2016-09-16 14:31:12,606 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT
2016-09-16 14:31:12,613 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT
```

I was really surprised to see the query for the insert of `Third` model before the one of the `First` one. It looks like the queries on the two different connections (once flushed by the commit command) are actioned simultaneously.

Is sqlalchemy doing some async trick? Is flask-sqlalchemy doing it with its custom sessions? Or I'm simply misunderstanding the log?

Comment: SQLAlchemy will perform queries that rely on other queries *after* other queries. Since the insert into `first` needs a value from the insert into `second` so it's executed at the end.

Comment: I realize that second must be executed before first, but i assumed that third would be executed last, since no other query rely on that.

Comment: I believe the algorithm is a bit simpler: queries that don't rely on other queries first, everything else second.

Comment: I think you could be right. I tried several times with some variations, and the query order seems not to be guaranteed, even with a single connection. I guess this could be problematic in some borderline cases...